# golang datastore get object

Tags: google-app-engine, go, entity, google-cloud-datastore

I need some guidance whether I am doing this correct. Im trying to get a single object of a car. This is how I create a car:

```
 car := &types.Car{
            Model:        req.Model,
            Regnr:        req.Regnr,
            Year:         req.Year,
            Type:         req.Type,
            CreationTime: time.Now(),
            Sold:         false,
        }
        //key := datastore.NewKey(context, "Car", "", 0, nil)

        _, err := datastore.Put(context, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(context, "Car", nil), car)
```

This is the way im trying to get the car again.

```
vars := mux.Vars(r)
        regnr := vars["regnr"]
        car := types.Car{}
        carKey := datastore.NewKey(context, "Car", regnr, 0, nil)
        err := datastore.Get(context, carKey, &car)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error getting car", err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
```

But I get the error: "error getting car datastore: no such entity"

I know I can do a GetAll and limit to one. But if im deleting an object, I need the entity. I guess. So I want to do it right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find the inserted entity, because it was saved with a different key than the one you try to get it by.

This line:

```
_, err := datastore.Put(context, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(context, "Car", nil), car)
```

Saves a `Car` entity with a newly created, incomplete key. If you try to save an entity with an incomplete key, the datastore will assign a (randomly distributed) unique *numeric ID* to it. A **numeric ID**, not a `string` `name`.

And then you try to get it with a key having a `string` `name`:

```
carKey := datastore.NewKey(context, "Car", regnr, 0, nil)
```

They will never match! The [*identifier*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Kinds_and_identifiers) part of an entity's key can either be

- a *key name* string
- or an integer *numeric ID*

But not both. So when you save an entity, its key either has a `string` id called *name* OR (exclusive OR) an `int64` id called *intID*.

Please do read my answer about entity identifiers: [Can I use AllocateIDs as “string” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29573089/1705598)

Your options are:

#### I. `regnr` as string name

Either use `regnr` as a `string` `name` if you do have guarantee it's unique, and it is always present (no entity to be saved without `regnr`):

```
carKey := datastore.NewKey(context, "Car", req.Regnr, 0, nil)
```

This is **not** an incomplete key if `req.Regnr` is not an empty string, and thus it will be used as the `string` `name` of the entity's key. Which means later you can get this entity by:

```
carKey := datastore.NewKey(context, "Car", regnr, 0, nil)
err := datastore.Get(context, carKey, &car)
```

#### II. `regnr` as "normal" property

Or define `regnr` as a "normal" property and save entities with an incomplete key, leaving the unique numeric ID assignment to the system. This won't limit you in finding entities by `regnr` as you can filter entities by it if it's an indexed property. In this alternative `regnr` is not part of the entity's key, so you can't use `datastore.Get()` to get an entity, you have to use a query, e.g. `datastore.NewQuery()`.

#### Comparision:

Pros of I. are that it's more compact, uses less datastore space, faster and easier to get entities by `regnr`.

Cons of I. are that you are responsible keeping `regnr` unique, and you can't save `Car` entities without `regnr` (which may or may not be a problem).

Comment: Thank you so much for a wonderful answer! :) I will go with the option of saving with regnr as key. But I have a question of whether I can declare in the struct of a car if a field is unique or not? like this: Regnr        string `json:"regnr" binding:"required"`. Although I think this is from mongodb.

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand Using the datastore, you can't specify if you want a field to be unique. You can't even make the Key a field of the struct to be filled automatically. Keys are usually passed to `Get()` and returned by `Put()`. You may add Key to the struct, but you have to set that manually. You can't specify Key to be unique, but since it is `regnr`, you said it is naturally unique. If by any chance you would save another `Car` with an existing `regnr`, that would overwrite the existing entity.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I create a car by inserting the regnr as key like this:

```
car := &types.Car{
            Model:        req.Model,
            Regnr:        req.Regnr,
            Year:         req.Year,
            Type:         req.Type,
            CreationTime: time.Now(),
            Sold:         false,
        }
        //key := datastore.NewKey(context, "Car", "", 0, nil)
        carKey := datastore.NewKey(context, "Car", req.Regnr, 0, nil)
        _, err := datastore.Put(context, carKey, car)
```

I can find it by doing as I wrote in the question. But is this a good way of doing it? I plan on keeping the regnr unique anyway if it is neccesary.